# почему не работает шейкер сортировка

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Header.h"
using namespace std;
#define N 80
void funcsortupgrade4(int array[], int size) {
    funcrand(array, N);
    int temp = 0, high = 1, low = N;
    size_t n = N;
    do {
        size_t newn = 0;
        while (high < low) {
            int flag = 0;
            for (size_t i = high; i < low; i++) {
                if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
                    flag = 1;
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i - 1];
                    array[i - 1] = temp;
                }
                newn = i;
            }
            n = newn;
            low--;
            for (int j = low; j > high; j--) {
                if (array[j - 1] < array[j]) {
                    flag = 1;
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = temp;
                }
                newn = j;
            }
            n = newn;
            high++;
            if (flag == 0) break;
 
        }
 
    } while (n > 1);
    funcprint(array, N);
}
```

Comment: она работает именно так как вы написали. Условие задачи покажите.

Comment: шейкер сортировки от  малейшего до крупнейшего

Comment: а почему здесь меняется, на убывание `if (array[j - 1] < array[j])` ?

Comment: AlexGlebe ?????

Comment: @rootuser распишите подробней свою проблему. И добавьте все это в вопрос, а не в виде комментария. Если вы получаете на выходе не то, что ожидаете. То приложите пример входных данных и выходных. Чтобы те, кто читает ваш вопрос поняли сразу в чем вообще проблема.

Comment: компилятор даже не выводит массив чего-то

Comment: @ПавелЕриков почему компилятор даже не выводит массив?

Comment: @rootuser Во-первых этим не компилятор занимается, во-вторых вы умете пользоваться отладчиком? Если бы умели поняли бы, что у вас получается бесконечный цикл. Если вы уж берете чужой код, то поищите хотя бы в гугле рабочии реализации.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков это я сделал просто надо было сделать шейкер сортировки с улучшением https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246848/правильно-ли-я-перенес-улучшенное-сортировки-пузырем-в-шейкер-сортировку

Comment: @rootuser в чем вообще состоит улучшение? Внутри `do ... while` у вас происходит сортировка массива (не правильная в вашем случае), а что делает `do ... while` тогда??

Comment: В том вопросе, который вы скинули выше. Там внешний цикл, хоть тоже ничего не улучшает, но он является заменой циклу `for`. У вас же внешний цикл и так `while` зачем еще один `while` не понятно.